# Partial Differential Equation (PDE) with Periodic Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the PDE

$$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

with periodic condition

$$v(x+2\pi,~y) = v(x,~y)$$

find the solution $v(x,y)$ satisfying the boundary conditions

$$v(x,0) =a\sin x \qquad v(x,1) = b \cos{2x}$$

After using separation of variables, I've found the following general solution

$$v(x,y) = (A \cos{\lambda x} + B \sin{\lambda x})(Ce^{\lambda y}+De^{-\lambda y})$$

The problem is, how do I use the periodic condition to get information on the PDE? Any insights on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to set $\lambda$ in such a way that the boundary condition is fulfilled. Since your solution should be $2\pi$ periodic in $x$ the choice $\lambda_n=n\in\mathbb{N_0}$ yields actually a family of suitable solutions:
$$
v(x,t)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (A_n \cos{n x} + B_n \sin{n x})(C_ne^{n y}+D_ne^{-n y})
$$
Now we insert the $y$ boundary conditions
$$
a\sin(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (A_n \cos{n x} + B_n \sin{n x})(C_n+D_n)
$$
which gives
$$
C_n+D_n=0 \mbox{ for } n\neq1\\
A_1=0\\
B_1=a\\
C_1+D_1=1
$$
Inserting yields
$$
v(x,t)=a\sin(x)(C_1e^{y}+(1-C_1)e^{-y})+\sum_{i\neq1} (A_n \cos{n x} + B_n \sin{n x})(C_ne^{n y}-C_ne^{-n y})
$$

Likewise the second condition gives
$$
b\sin(2x)=a\sin(x)(C_1e^{1}+(1-C_1)e^{-1})+\sum_{i\neq1} (A_n \cos{n x} + B_n \sin{n x})(C_ne^{n}-C_ne^{-n})
$$

$$
C_n=0 \mbox{ for } n\neq1,2\\
A_2=0\\
B_2=b\\
C_2e^{2}-C_2e^{-2}=1\\
C_1e^{1}+(1-C_1)e^{-1}=0
$$
which finally gives the solution as:
$$
v(x,t)=a\sin(x)\frac{e^{1-y}-e^{y-1}}{e-e^{-1}}+b\sin(2x)\frac{e^{2y}-e^{-2y}}{e^{2}-e^{-2}}
$$

Note that for this specific example of $y$ boundary conditions the full family of solutions was not necessary it would have been sufficient to just take the sum of the two needed functions ($\lambda\in\{1,2\}$ and only the sine functions). However the presented methods also works for any set of $y$ boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much Max! This question was on my nerves for some weeks. Actually, I was able to reach the first $y$ bound step (to find $\lambda = n$), but I could not manage to tell what $B_1$ and $C_1 + D_1$ were. If you do not mind one more question, why can we affirm that $C_1 + D_1 = 1$ and $B_1 = a$ and not the other way around?

Comment: Oh, and for the second boundary, we have $b \cos{2x}$ instead of $b \sin{2x}$, but do not worry, I will do the calculations. Thanks again!

Comment: Regarding the first question: Id doesnt really matter. In essence the four degrees of freedom introduced by the four unkowns $A,B,C,D$ are a little bit too much so you have some freedom there. But in the end the result should always be the same.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I misread the second boundary condition.

Comment: So basically, since I have these degrees of freedom, I can choose the values that is easier for me and, of course, that fits the equation?

Comment: So basically regarding index $1$ the condition are $(C_1+D_1)\cdot A1=a,(C_1+D_1)\cdot B1=0,(eC_1+e^{-1}D_1)\cdot A1=0,(eC_1+e^{-1}D_1)\cdot B1=0$. Now in terms of the variables this system is underdetermined but whatever solution you choose for this system you will always get the same solution for $v$.